# Set expire date for users

Tags: bash, scripts

I use ubuntu 12.04, i have a file **"user.cfg"** and i put in this file the users like this

```
F: user pass { enddate=2017-01-24 }
```

This file existe in **/var/etc/**

[Here's image of the file](http://e.top4top.net/p_62whcs1.png)

I want a script for erasing automatically expired user from this file **"user.cfg"**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

## Reading "/var/etc/user.cfg", saving the line being read in variable "line"
while read -r line; do

    ## Getting the username from "user.cfg", saving in variable "user"
    user="$(grep -Po '^F:\s+\K[^\s]+' <<<"$line")"

    ## Getting the expiry date from "user.cfg", saving in variable "exp_cfg"  
    exp_cfg="$(grep -Po 'enddate=\K[^\s]+' <<<"$line")"

        ## Getting expiry time, days since Epoch from 
        ## "/etc/shadow" into variable "exp_shadow"
        exp_shadow="$(sudo grep -Po "^$user:.*:\K[^:]+(?=:[^:]*$)" /etc/shadow)"

            ## Check if "exp_shadow" is not Null
            [[ -n $exp_shadow ]] &&

            ## If not null, then convert the date from "exp_cfg" into days 
            ## since epoch and then check if its less than "exp_shadow"
            ## Replace ">" with "<" if you want to see the expired accounts :)
            (( $exp_shadow > $(($(date '+%s' <<<"$exp_cfg")/86400)) )) &&

            ## If so, print the line
            echo "$line"

done </var/etc/user.cfg
```

Save it as e.g. `user_exp_check.sh`, now you can see the users with non-expired account by running the following (assuming you are on the script's directory):

```
bash user_exp_check.sh
```

To save the output in a new file e.g. `new_user.cfg`:

```
bash user_exp_check.sh >new_user.cfg
```

Then you can remove the old `/var/etc/user.cfg` file.

Comment: ِCan i use this script without removing the old  /var/etc/user.cfg file?  i need this file as it is with the same name

Comment: @timovitch The script will not remove the `/var/etc/user.cfg` .. If you want you can remove it manually later, that's what I have mentioned in the last line of the answer..

Comment: Not working with me ... After the run it does not change anything in the user.cfg file

Comment: @timovitch Please read my answer carefully, it won't change the file in-place..don't you see any output on the screen?

Comment: No,when i run it, i not saw anything on the screen ... and the user that has a expiry date not be deleted from the user.cfg file

Comment: @timovitch Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/735587/edit) your question and add the `user.cfg` file you are talking about..

Comment: I've added a picture of the mentioned file **user.cfg**